# How to understand which xorg.conf.d is actually used by the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, xorg.conf

If I run in Ubuntu 17.04 `locate xorg.conf.d | grep d$`, here is what I get:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Is it normal to have two folders like these, or is it some side-effect of upgrading the distribution, which I did just before?

Which is, out of the two, the folder that is really used by the system. I have to add a configuration file and I do not know whether to add it in the one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

According to `man xorg.conf`,

```
When the Xorg server is started by the “root” user, the config directory search locations are as follows:

    /etc/X11/<cmdline> 
    /usr/etc/X11/<cmdline> 
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d 
    /usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

where <cmdline> is the path specified with the −configdir command line option (which may be absolute or relative).
Finally, configuration files will also be searched for in directories reserved for system use. These are to separate configuration files from the vendor or 3rd party packages from those of local administration. These files are found in the following directories:

    /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

So `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` is where you should put your configuration, and `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` is where the software will put configuration files.